# Concise, fast singleton subclasses

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, singleton, subclass

I'm writing, in C#, an interpreter for a dynamic language, and implementing primitive functions as an abstract class Primitive with a virtual Apply method, where each actual primitive function will be a subclass that overrides Apply.

(An alternative would be to only have the class Primitive and store a function pointer for Apply. However, making it a virtual method seems likely to be slightly faster, and this code will be run very frequently, so a small speedup is worth having.)

Obviously I could go ahead and create a full-blown class file for each primitive function, but I can't help feeling there ought to be a slightly more concise way of doing things than creating dozens of tiny class files.

In Java I'd use the anonymous subclass syntax to create and instantiate a subclass all in one expression, but I don't think C# has an exact counterpart.

What is the best way of doing this in C#?

Comment: `making it a virtual method seems likely to be slightly faster` -- This is almost certainly premature optimization.  Measure it, and see if it's really going to matter.

Comment: C# has anonymous types.  Don't know if that's the same thing as Java.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks - C# anonymous types don't support methods, and while measurement is the ideal, I'm not sure how to create a realistic test without doing the job twice; a synthetic micro-benchmark might optimize differently in the JIT.

Comment: What does the abstract class primitive contain, other than an overridable Apply method?

Comment: Also an override of ToString, which gives the name of the primitive function.

Comment: You can put more than one class in a file, whether or not you make them subclasses as in Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I wouldn't *assume* that a virtual method call will be faster than a delegate. Maybe it will, maybe it won't - but if performance is *really* that important to you, you should measure that. It would be really simple to code this using lambda expressions, particularly if *all* you're trying to represent is a function:

```
public static readonly Func<int, int> Addition = (x, y) => x + y;
public static readonly Func<int, int> Subtraction = (x, y) => x - y;
// etc
```

(I'm just guessing at the sorts of operation here, as we don't know the details.)

There's no particularly tiny syntax for subclasses in C#, but for semi-singletons like this 
I find nested classes work well... similar to Java enums:

```
public abstract class Primitive
{
    public static readonly Primitive Addition = new AdditionPrimitive();
    public static readonly Primitive Subtraction = new SubtractionPrimitive();

    // Prevent outside instantiation
    private Primitive()
    {
    }

    public abstract int Apply(int x, int y);

    // Anything else you want

    private class AdditionPrimitive : Primitive
    {
        public override int Apply(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }

    private class SubtractionPrimitive : Primitive
    {
        public override int Apply(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. Overrides of ToString are also needed, which will fit without difficulty in the nested classes; the result will be a bit verbose by line count, but it's basically just copy pasted boilerplate all tucked away within one class file, so it should work fine.